# MYSQL: Como fazer um fechamento do mês do dia 26 ao dia 26

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho um formulário de cadastro de serviços realizados, e no final do mês eu tenho de analisar o fechamento dos custos do montante de serviços, e pagar as prestadoras de serviço.

Porém o fechamento do mês é todo dia 26, então como eu poderia apresentar somente os serviços do dia (27 de JANEIRO --- ate --- 26 de FEVEREIRO)?

segue o código abaixo:
[image: BANCO DE DADOS]

```
<?php
  $soma_custos = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT SUM(custosgerais) FROM custos WHERE MONTH(data_baixa) BETWEEN $mes AND $mes");  
?>
```

Porém o código acima por enquanto somente esta me mostrando os serviços do dia 1 ao dia 30 do mesmo mês.

> Preciso pegar do dia 27 do mês passado ate dia 26 do mês atual.

Comment: Bem vindo Gabriel Pires, caso alguma resposta solucionou seu problema não deixe de marcá-la como `aceita` veja como e porque nesse post https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score 4):

Basta especificar o dia e assim pegar tudo que está entre as datas:

```
SELECT SUM(custosgerais) 
FROM custos 
WHERE data_baixa >= '2017-01-26 00:00:00' AND data_baixa < '2017-02-26 00:00:00'
```

Você também pode usar o `BETWEEN`, caso prefira:

```
SELECT SUM(custosgerais) 
FROM custos 
WHERE (data_baixa BETWEEN '2017-01-26 00:00:00' AND '2017-02-25 23:59:59')
```

Answer (score 0):

> A pergunta "Preciso pegar do dia 27 do **mês passado** ate dia 26 do **mês atual**."

A clausula where nesse caso é:

```
WHERE data_baixa >= DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y-%m-27')
AND data_baixa <= DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-27')
```

Na tabela de exemplo abaixo, o que se quer é a soma da coluna `custosgerais` das linhas selecionadas em azul, ou seja, entre o dia 27 do mês passado e 26 do corrente mês.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Fazendo o select teremos como retorno a soma** = `122`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Destarte, é só rodar o script no dia do fechamento para obter a soma necessária. Se rodar antes do dia do fechamento vai obter a soma até esse dia.